# sinon stub namespaced function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, namespaces, metaprogramming, sinon

I'm having some issues using sinon stubs and it may stem from how I'm implementing namespacing on the module that I'm looking to stub. Methods directly defined on the prototype are stubbed as I would expect.

```
...my module.js 
const Constructor = require('./constructor') //...just exports a singleton

/* Need to namespace some of my functions and retain the `this` context */

Object.defineProperty(Constructor.prototype, 'es', {
  get: function() {
    return {
      method: require('./implementations/doesSomething.js').bind(this)
    }
  }
});

module.exports = Constructor;




/* ...testFile.js */
const Constructor = require('./constructor');
const instance = new Constructor();
const sinon = require('sinon');

sinon.stub(instance.es, 'method', function() {
   return 'hijacked original method'
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Arcath I'm not getting any errors, it's just not stubbing the method at all. I also noticed if I put a console.log to check if it is indeed a sinon stub and it's not.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [on the Sinon issue tracker](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1472#issuecomment-311318585), the problem here is that using a plain `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop')` call does something else than plainly creating it using assignment (`obj['prop'] = ...`).

Generally, if you try defining your property without `Object.defineProperty` it will be stubbable, but using `defineProperty` (without creating a special configuration) will make it impossible to stub   the property. The reason is simply that the [default values for `writeable` and `configurable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Writable_attribute) are `false`! You cannot `delete` them or change them. And if you can't do that, then Sinon won't help you. So, generally, you need to add `writeable: true, configurable: true` in your property definition.

**Now there was one more thing I forgot to answer originally:**
You are not trying to wrap a function on `Constructor.prototype.es.method` - what you are trying to wrap is the function on the object returned by the getter on the property for `es`. That will *never* work. *Why?* Simply because the returned object is *never the same*. You are creating a new object around `method` each time. If you really need to replace/stub the `method` property, you actually need to replace the entire `Constructor.prototype.es` property instead. If you need this namespacing, you can vastly simplify this, and also enable stubbing, like this:

```
Constructor.prototype.es = {};

Object.defineProperty(Constructor.prototype.es, 'method', {
  get: function() {
    return someFunction.bind(this);
  },
  writeable: true,
  configurable:true
}
```

An expanded, fully working example ([Gist for download](https://gist.github.com/515baa042a7c06cdd18c73ec751ff994)):

```js
// constructor.js
const someFunction = function(){
    return this.value;
}

function Constructor(){ };
Constructor.prototype.es = { value : 100 };

Object.defineProperty(Constructor.prototype.es, 'method', {
  get: function() {
    return someFunction.bind(this);
  },
  writeable: true,
  configurable:true
});

// test.js
const instance = new Constructor();

console.log(instance.es.method()) // => 100

// using this won't work:
// sinon.stub(instance.__proto__.es, 'method').returns(42);
// because the getter is returning a _new_ function each time
// therefore you need to attack the actual getter function:

const stub = sinon.stub(instance.__proto__.es, 'method').value(()=>42);
console.log(instance.es.method()) // => 42
stub.get(()=>()=>84);
console.log(instance.es.method()) // => 84
stub.restore();
console.log(instance.es.method()) // => 100

// the above is working on the prototype, can't we do this on the instance?
// yes, we can, but remember that the `es` object is shared, so we
// can avoid modifying it by shadowing it further down the prototype
instance.es = { method: sinon.stub().returns(256) };
console.log(instance.es.method()) // => 256
delete instance.es
console.log(instance.es.method()) // => 100
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sinon@2.3.5/pkg/sinon.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. Although the fact that my constructor is a singleton it will always be the same object. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I implemented this solution and I'm getting this issue
    
**TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property method as function at checkWrappedMethod (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/util/core/wrap-method.js:41:21)`**

because the logic is looking for a value prop which is not specified in the current configuration.

Comment: I have added a fully running example:
https://gist.github.com/515baa042a7c06cdd18c73ec751ff994

It demonstrates all the different techniques and is well commented.

Comment: Hey thanks for the example. I noticed that the working example worked because the value is in the context of the es object you've created. For my use case the value property would exist on the instance in which this solution wouldn't work.

I didn't manage to get it work by instead defining the namespace in the Constructor itself, that way the this context will be instance.

Thanks for taking the time to look into this!

Comment: Yeah, you would never get the `this` pointer to point to each instance, as long as the instance would be shared on the prototype, so creating it in the constructor with closure binding would fix it, as you say.